# complex analysis Laurent series around no singularity point?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

hi Guys I am trying to determine a series for the following function:

$$f(x)=\frac{2z}{(z+i)(z-1)}$$ about $|z-1|<\frac{1}{2}$

I already developed partial fractions:

$$\frac{1 + i}{z + i} + \frac{1 - i}{z - 1}$$

but got a problem with: $$\frac{1 + i}{z + i}$$ since I cannot find any Laurent valid series there for the point $|z-1|<1/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you actually mean an expansion centered at $z=1$, which will converge on $|z-1|<1/2$ (and a little more $|z-1|<\sqrt{2}$), expand $$\frac{1+i}{z+i}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{z-1}{i+1}}=\sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^n\frac{(z-1)^n}{(1+i)^n}$$

The point $z=1$ will have to be excluded due to the other term: $\frac{1-i}{z-1}$.

Comment: my new question is: is that valid por the $|z-1|<1/2$ condition? since $$\frac{|z-1|}{i+1}<1$$ does not equal $|z-1|<1/2$

Comment: @anonjulianXD Yes, a/the power series centered at $z=1$ will necessarily converge all the way to the point $z=i$. So, a region strictly larger except for $z=1$. At $z=1$ there shouldn't be a regular point of the expansion, because there is a pole already there.

Comment: thanks I got it, it really helped me since I was used to evaluate series only until the singularities. 

pdta:(last question) then I guess the second condition: $$\frac{1 - i}{z - 1}$$ is the same function since it's a taylor series centered at a singularity. right?

Comment: @anonjulianXD Take into account that Laurent series converge on annuli in which the center is the center of the series. Any Laurent series converging exactly on $|z-1|<1/2$ will have to be centered at $z=1$. By uniqueness, that series will be forced to be the series obtained by the procedure above.

Comment: @anonjulianXD Yes, $\frac{1-i}{z-1}$ has only one Laurent series expansion centered at $z=1$, and it is itself.